# Use glycerin to help your gecko shed?

Tags: reptiles, geckos, molting

Can you use glycerin to help your gecko shed? I've used it on a burmese python that had not shed the caps on his eyes for quite sometime. And it helped tremendously. Do you think it would be just as safe?

Comment: I'm not sure about glycerin, but you could also try cutting open a Vitamin D capsule and using that.

Answer (score 1):

if this is a leopard gecko, I find keeping the skin moist is enough and personally never tried glycerin. Water does seem to run straight off the skin on its own but keeping them moist for a while helps a lot, try a warm takeaway container with damp paper towel. If they're stressed out after and don't let you hold them, rubbing the toes (if those are problem areas) with cotton buds while they're standing still can help pull it all off like a sock. Be really careful around the eyes and tail though, it's less risky to simply raise the humidity in the tank for a few days